# Iterative hexdump to find a value

Tags: find, hexdump

As you can see the output of a hexdump command. I would like to iterate throughout the hard disk (or some limit) in order to find a value as a `while-loop`, in example `APSB` value.

The step are in my case is `4096` bytes

1. Iteration 1: `hexdump -n 4096 -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s 0`
2. Iteration 2: `hexdump -n 4096 -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s 4096`
3. Iteration 3: `hexdump -n 4096 -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s 9192`

Here a related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/713636/117555) of How I thought the previous iteration.

But, how to find a value inside the `hexdump` output?

Is it possible?

```
sh-3.2# hexdump -n 4096 -Cv /dev/disk0s1 -s 0
00000000  8d 1c 09 48 65 8c 3c 6e  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...He.<n........|
00000010  bd 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  00 f4 01 00 00 00 00 00  |NXSB............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a8 8d 96 da 5a 95 46 e6  |............Z.F.|
00000050  82 3e fb 1e 40 7d 3e 79  16 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.>..@}>y........|
00000060  be 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  10 00 00 00 84 04 00 00  |................|
00000070  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  0a 00 00 00 e2 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  34 1e 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |4...............|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  06 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  08 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  0a 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you really need to *"value inside the hexdump output"* - or do you just need to find a particular byte sequence in a binary file?

Comment: Yes, I need to find the sequence...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319878/using-grep-to-search-for-hex-strings-in-a-file - 
https://superuser.com/questions/627862/how-can-i-grep-a-hex-value-in-a-string-in-a-binary-file - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180081/binary-grep-on-linux/17168777#17168777

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807855/grep-only-a-part-of-a-text-file - 
https://serverfault.com/questions/328101/how-do-i-grep-through-binary-files-that-look-like-text